# Evaluate $\iiint_V(x+zy)^2dxdydz$ where V is bounded by $x^2+ y^2 = 2z, z = 2 $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Evaluate $\iiint_V(x+zy)^2dxdydz$ where V is bounded by $x^2+ y^2
 = 2z, z = 2 $.

---

$x^2+ y^2=4$ for $z =2$ so $z\in{[0,2]}$ and $y\in{[0,{\sqrt{4-x^2}}]}$. Is it correct and how can I find $x$ interval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to use cylindrical coordinates here. Your equations become $r^2=2z$ and $z=2$. So, $z$ lies in the interval $[0,2]$ and, for each $z$, $r\leqslant\sqrt{2z}$. Therefore, compute the integral$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2\int_0^{\sqrt{2z}}r\bigl(r\cos(\theta)+zr\sin(\theta)\bigr)^2\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm d\theta$$

Comment: Isn't $z$ in [0,2] interval?

Comment: Yes. I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: I have only 1 question : how do we know that interval for $\theta$ is [0, 2$\pi$]?

Comment: Because that region has points all around the $z$ axis. If we had, say, the condition $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$, this would imply that $\lvert x-1\rvert\leqslant1$ and therefore $0\leqslant x\leqslant2$. So, in this case, $\cos\theta\geqslant0$ and so $-\frac\pi2\leqslant\theta\leqslant\frac\pi2$.